# stretch table completely out to the width of the page

Tags: tables

I made a table, but i would like to stretch it completely out to the width of the page. I used following code:
I appreciate all your help

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabulary}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} ccccccc}
Variable                                                                               & Data & $\delta$     & t-stat & P\textgreater{}$|t|$ & P\textgreater F & $\overline{R}^2$   &      $\Delta\overline{R}^2$ \\ \hline
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Macroeconomic predictor\\   variables\end{tabular}} &           &        &                    &                     &        &            \\ \hline
Dividend-price ratio*                                                                   & 1871-2017 & -0,97 & -3,08  & 0,2                & 0,33                & 0,65   & 0,6        \\
Dividend yield*                                                                         & 1871-2017 & -0,98 & -3,11  & 0,2                & 0,32                & 0,73   & 0,64       \\
Earnings-price ratio**                                                                   & 1871-2017 & -0,80 & -2,61  & 0,9                & 1,91                & 0,65   & 0,46       \\
Dividend-earnings ratio**                                                                & 1871-2017 & -0,72 & -2,50  & 1,3                & 4,40                & 0,29   & 0,33       \\
Conditional variance***                                                                   & 1885-2017 & -0,73 & -2,31  & 2,1                & 6,96                & 0,25   & 0,31       \\
Book-to-market ratio***                                                                   & 1921-2017 & -0,91 & -1,54  & 12,4               & 9,84                & 0,72   & 0,33       \\
Cross-Sectional Premium                                                                & 1937-2017 & 0,18  & 0,35   & 72,6               & 21,73               & 0,14   & -0,11      \\
Net equity expansions***                                                                  & 1926-2017 & -0,56 & -0,85  & 39,4               & 7,48                & 0,44   & 0,07       \\
T-bill rate                                                                            & 1920-2017 & -0,64 & -1,13  & 25,7               & 36,87               & 0,07   & 0,14       \\
Long-term yield                                                                        & 1919-2017 & -0,59 & -1,07  & 28,4               & 52,22               & 0,03   & 0,11       \\
Long-term return**                                                                       & 1926-2017 & -0,59 & 1,07   & 28,4               & 3,39                & 0,32   & 0,18       \\
Term spread                                                                            & 1920-2017 & -0,62 & -1,10  & 27,2               & 29,69               & 0,1    & 0,13       \\
Default yield spread                                                                   & 1919-2017 & -0,94 & -1,69  & 9,1                & 20,45               & 0,42   & 0,34       \\
Default return spread                                                                  & 1926-2017 & -0,69 & -1,09  & 27,4               & 13,89               & 0,16   & 0,15       \\
Inflation***                                                                              & 1913-2017 & -0,75 & -1,51  & 13,1               & 5,04                & 0,3    & 0,25       \\ \hline
\textbf{Technical predictor variables}                                                 &           &       &        &                    &                     &        &            \\ \hline
Past return**                                                                            & 1871-2017 & -0,62 & -2,12  & 3,5                & 1,28                & 0,75   & 0,26       \\
Volatility*                                                                             & 1871-2017 & -0,80 & -2,67  & 0,8                & 0,24                & 0,7    & 0,46       \\
Momentum rule (12)***                                                                     & 1871-2017 & -0,68 & -2,25  & 2,5                & 6,58                & 0,29   & 0,31       \\
Simple Moving Average (10)**                                                             & 1871-2017 & -0,74 & -2,43  & 1,5                & 4,98                & 0,33   & -4,639     \\ \hline
\end{tabulary}
\caption{Badtimes}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: This is my table using tabular*, \hline is too long, and thats why i would like to strech colums out[image: tabular*]

Comment: I see that its current state is good enough. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: I think it looks good, but i think that stretching colums would make it easier readable

Comment: making the columns further apart would just make the table harder for your readers to read. Also `\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} ccccccc}` should be `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} ccccccc}` as `tabulary` can not do anything with `c` columns or `\extracolsep`.

Comment: Thank for for your feedback JouleV and David Carlisle, i initially used tabular* ,  however i noticed that table looked weird. see picture

Comment: Thank you so much Bernard, this table is perfect! have a lovely day

Answer (score 2):

in `tabulary` environment the macro `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` doesn't work. in it you also need to use its column specifiers (`L`, `C`, `R` or `J`). Using them and removing `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` you will almost obtain for what you after. however with `tabular*` (instead of the `tabulary`) table environment, using macro `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` and `S` columns defined in the `siunitx` package ypo will obtain better result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,},
         table-auto-round,
         table-format=-1.2}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
            lc SS SS SS}
Variable & Data & {$\delta$}  & {t-stat}
         & {$\text{P} > |t|$} & {$\text{P} > \text{F}$}
         & {$\overline{R}^2$} & {$\Delta\overline{R}^2$}            \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\bfseries Macroeconomic predictor variables}     \\
    \midrule
Dividend-price ratio*
        & 1871-2017 & -0,97 & -3,08 &  0,2 &  0,33 & 0,65 &  0,6    \\
Dividend yield*
        & 1871-2017 & -0,98 & -3,11 &  0,2 &  0,32 & 0,73 &  0,64   \\
Earnings-price ratio**
        & 1871-2017 & -0,80 & -2,61 &  0,9 &  1,91 & 0,65 &  0,46   \\
Dividend-earnings ratio**
        & 1871-2017 & -0,72 & -2,50 &  1,3 &  4,40 & 0,29 &  0,33   \\
Conditional variance***
        & 1885-2017 & -0,73 & -2,31 &  2,1 &  6,96 & 0,25 &  0,31   \\
Book-to-market ratio***
        & 1921-2017 & -0,91 & -1,54 & 12,4 &  9,84 & 0,72 &  0,33   \\
Cross-Sectional Premium
        & 1937-2017 &  0,18 &  0,35 & 72,6 & 21,73 & 0,14 & -0,11   \\
Net equity expansions***
        & 1926-2017 & -0,56 & -0,85 & 39,4 &  7,48 & 0,44 &  0,07   \\
T-bill rate
        & 1920-2017 & -0,64 & -1,13 & 25,7 & 36,87 & 0,07 &  0,14   \\
Long-term yield
        & 1919-2017 & -0,59 & -1,07 & 28,4 & 52,22 & 0,03 &  0,11   \\
Long-term return**
        & 1926-2017 & -0,59 &  1,07 & 28,4 &  3,39 & 0,32 &  0,18   \\
Term spread
        & 1920-2017 & -0,62 & -1,10 & 27,2 & 29,69 & 0,1  &  0,13   \\
Default yield spread
        & 1919-2017 & -0,94 & -1,69 &  9,1 & 20,45 & 0,42 &  0,34   \\
Default return spread
        & 1926-2017 & -0,69 & -1,09 & 27,4 & 13,89 & 0,16 &  0,15   \\
Inflation***
        & 1913-2017 & -0,75 & -1,51 & 13,1 &  5,04 & 0,3  &  0,25   \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\bfseries Technical predictor variables}         \\
    \midrule
Past return**
        & 1871-2017 & -0,62 & -2,12 &  3,5 &  1,28 & 0,75 &  0,26   \\
Volatility*
        & 1871-2017 & -0,80 & -2,67 &  0,8 &  0,24 & 0,7  &  0,46   \\
Momentum rule (12)***
        & 1871-2017 & -0,68 & -2,25 &  2,5 &  6,58 & 0,29 &  0,31   \\
Simple Moving Average (10)**
        & 1871-2017 & -0,74 & -2,43 &  1,5 &  4,98 & 0,33 & -4,639  \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Badtimes}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Answer (score 1):

Your table can fit the textwidth, with this simpler code, based on `tabularx`  and `siunitx`, for an alignment of the numbers on the decimal comma (furthermore the minus sign won't be a hyphen dash!):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\sisetup{copy-decimal-marker, table-number-alignment=center, table-format=-1.2}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XcSSS[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=2.2]SS[table-format=-1.3]}
Variable & Data & {$\delta$} & {t-stat} & {P\textgreater{}$|t|$} & {P\textgreater F} & {$\overline{R}^2$} & {$\Delta\overline{R}^2$} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries Macroeconomic predictor variables} \\ \hline
Dividend-price ratio* & 1871-2017 & -0,97 & -3,08 & 0,2 & 0,33 & 0,65 & 0,6 \\
Dividend yield* & 1871-2017 & -0,98 & -3,11 & 0,2 & 0,32 & 0,73 & 0,64 \\
Earnings-price ratio** & 1871-2017 & -0,80 & -2,61 & 0,9 & 1,91 & 0,65 & 0,46 \\
Dividend-earnings ratio** & 1871-2017 & -0,72 & -2,50 & 1,3 & 4,40 & 0,29 & 0,33 \\
Conditional variance*** & 1885-2017 & -0,73 & -2,31 & 2,1 & 6,96 & 0,25 & 0,31 \\
Book-to-market ratio*** & 1921-2017 & -0,91 & -1,54 & 12,4 & 9,84 & 0,72 & 0,33 \\
Cross-Sectional Premium & 1937-2017 & 0,18 & 0,35 & 72,6 & 21,73 & 0,14 & -0,11 \\
Net equity expansions*** & 1926-2017 & -0,56 & -0,85 & 39,4 & 7,48 & 0,44 & 0,07 \\
T-bill rate & 1920-2017 & -0,64 & -1,13 & 25,7 & 36,87 & 0,07 & 0,14 \\
Long-term yield & 1919-2017 & -0,59 & -1,07 & 28,4 & 52,22 & 0,03 & 0,11 \\
Long-term return** & 1926-2017 & -0,59 & 1,07 & 28,4 & 3,39 & 0,32 & 0,18 \\
Term spread & 1920-2017 & -0,62 & -1,10 & 27,2 & 29,69 & 0,1 & 0,13 \\
Default yield spread & 1919-2017 & -0,94 & -1,69 & 9,1 & 20,45 & 0,42 & 0,34 \\
Default return spread & 1926-2017 & -0,69 & -1,09 & 27,4 & 13,89 & 0,16 & 0,15 \\
Inflation*** & 1913-2017 & -0,75 & -1,51 & 13,1 & 5,04 & 0,3 & 0,25 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries Technical predictor variables} \\ \hline
Past return** & 1871-2017 & -0,62 & -2,12 & 3,5 & 1,28 & 0,75 & 0,26 \\
Volatility* & 1871-2017 & -0,80 & -2,67 & 0,8 & 0,24 & 0,7 & 0,46 \\
Momentum rule (12)*** & 1871-2017 & -0,68 & -2,25 & 2,5 & 6,58 & 0,29 & 0,31 \\
Simple Moving Average (10)** & 1871-2017 & -0,74 & -2,43 & 1,5 & 4,98 & 0,33 & -4,639 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Badtimes}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]